# Table cell in IE9 sizes incorrectly. Works fine in other browsers

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9

Please look at the following page in IE9..

www.homextreme.co.za/default_test.aspx

I have added borders on some of the tables for debugging purposes

On the left choose any region from the dropdown, the page will refresh..
On the right you will see there is now a gap below the table on the right.

I have googled for ages and searched for IE9 table bug fixes and tried them but for the life of me I cannot get that cell to size correctly. Can somebody please help me with a solution for this?

[Link to screenshot before I expand the directory on the left.](http://www.homextreme.co.za/images/screen1.png)

[Link to screenshot after...](http://www.homextreme.co.za/images/screen2.png)

Thanks

Comment: Provide an annotated screenshot. I cannot see the difference.

Comment: Ok I have added a link to screenshots

Comment: Point a marker where I need to look, and scale both images the same size please.

Answer (score 0):

After making a selection from the list you get a long list on the left column. Since all the content is inside a bigger table (oy tables inside tables inside tables), the right column has to expand vertically.

In the right column there are two cells on on top of the other one (plus the one in the middle for spacing). The one in the top includes the table with the space you don't want, the cell in the bottom has a bunch of other smaller sections. The top cell expands vertically and ends up being taller than the content, and that's the extra space you see. If you change the vertical alignment (`vAlign`) of that cell (1st row, 3rd cell) to `top`, you'll see the space move to the top.

The reason it doesn't show up in other browsers is that they probably have different row height algorithms and make the 1st row as small as possible and leave the rest to the 2nd and 3rd. And then IE uses percentages or makes the rows proportional to the content or something.

I'm not sure what to suggest you do to fix this. If you're going to stick to tables for layout, just use one row and have a cell for each column, and keep the content of each column in the same cell instead of splitting it in rows.